# ¿Como cambiar el modo de descarga de archivos .csv de mi aplicación ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, devexpress

Tengo un botón que me exporta en csv la información de un Grid, está configurado para que el dilimitador sea "," pero al momento de pasar a producción en un servidor Microsoft, el delimitador es ";" como puedo solucionarlo. Encontré cambiando la configuración del IIS, pero no funcionó.

Comment: Avaces eso es configuración del office, imagino que cuando se genera el archivo lo abres en block de notas y ya cambio.
puedes pegar el código con el que generas el CSV?

Comment: IIS no tiene nada que ver con la forma de descarga, solo sirve archivos, asi que si tenes un cambio de delimitador, esta dado por otra cosa.

Comment: Que mecanismo usas para generar el CSV?

Comment: Buenas tardes, este error se genera por el hecho de que la configuración de ambas máquinas para la separación de la información es distinta, si un excel tiene de manera determinada que su separador sea en ; o bien en , va a presentar conflictos con esto.